# Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined

My bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/allscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js",
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.all.js",
                    //"~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.culture.ru.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.culture.kk.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.messages.ru-RU.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.culture.ru-RU.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/lightbox.js",
                    "~/Scripts/script.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js",
                    "~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js"));
```

Comment: Where is the refernce error?

Comment: jQuery(function(){jQuery("#Furnitures").kendoGrid({"columns":[{"title":"Name","field":"Name","filterable"........................................

Comment: Please edit your question with the nessecary code including your bundle inclusion and your JavaScript implementation. You have tagged as kendo mvc but only shown your bundle.

Comment: Where in your document are you including this bundle?

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where I tried to upgrade Kendo and all the files were moved out of `Scripts/kendo` and into `Scripts/kendo/<version>`.

In that case, you can either add the version to your bundle config or just move the files back to the kendo directory. You'll have to do this for both Scripts and Content.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the below lines in my /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/telerik")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/telerik")
```

after these lines:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because a bundle may already exist which references jQuery. It may be that one or more of the files you're referencing are missing or in a different location. The following link from Telerik may help you figure out what is happening: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting

If you look at the link it mentions:

> If using ASP.NET bundles move the Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") block before the Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC JavaScript files.

Failing that edit your question with the whole contents of the BundleConfig.cs file so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me moving this line

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/cultures/kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js"></script>
```

at the end of the javascript references in my _layout